# keypress on iframe document gets whole html as target (not exact node)

Tags: jquery, iframe, keypress

I have an iframe with designMode="on" *(Yeah - I know this is bad thing)*

I should catch clicking on it and keypressing and echo the node name of target element.

```
$(function() {

var editor = $("#editor")[0].contentWindow;
var doc = editor.document;
editor.document.designMode = "on";
doc.open();
doc.write('<div id="dummy">test</div>');
doc.close();
// find iframe body
var $body = $("#editor").contents().find('#dummy').parent();
// clean after finding
$body.html('<div>Hello</div>');

var report = function(e) {
    $("#result").html(
    $("#result").html() + " " + e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase());
};

$body.click(report);

// $body.keypress(report) -> doesn't work
// only $(doc).keypress works:
$(doc).keypress(report);
});
```

When I click on word "Hello" - I get "div" - it's correct, but when I keypress on it - i get "html" instead "div". How to fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/fJLTG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of google .. this might help you:

```
var f = document.getElementById('iframe_id');
var fwin = f.contentWindow || f.contentDocument;
fwin.document.designMode = 'on';

var evt_key = function (e) {
    e = e || fwin.event;
    var range = null, ret = null;

    if (fwin.document.selection) {
        range = fwin.document.selection.createRange();
        ret = range.parentElement();
    }
    else if (fwin.window.getSelection) {
        var range = fwin.window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        ret = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode || fwin.document;
    }

    fwin.parent.do_some_thing(ret);
};

if (fwin.document.attachEvent) {
    fwin.document.attachEvent('onkeypress', evt_key);
}
else if (fwin.document.addEventListener) {
    fwin.document.addEventListener('keypress', evt_key, false);
}
```

all credis to jetcook  (http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_25589672.html)

Answer (score 3):

I created a function, it can work keypress.

> ```
>     var reportDomPath = function (e) {
>         // 1. get caret cursor position node
>         var selection, range, node, i_node;
>         var tag = null;
> ```

```
        var iframe = document.getElementById('editor');
        var iframe_win = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;
        e = e || fwin.event;
        if (iframe_win.getSelection) {
            try {   // FF
                selection = iframe_win.getSelection();
                range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
                node = range.commonAncestorContainer;
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            try {   // IE
                selection = iframe_win.document.selection;
                range = selection.createRange();
                node = range.parentElement();
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //2. parse DOM Path until HTML. The top of the "HTML" is "Document"

        i_node = node;
        do {
            if (i_node.nodeType != 1)
                continue;
            // get all of DOM Note
            if (tag == null) {
                tag = i_node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            } else {
                tag = tag + ">>" + i_node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            }
            // do_some_thing for each Node : obj.addClass('active'); or obj.removeClass('active'); and so on.
        } while (i_node = i_node.parentNode)

        //do_some_thing for all of note fwin.parent.do_some_thing(ret);

        var keyCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode;

        $("#result").html(
                $("#result").html() + "node dom path: " + tag + '   key' + e.type + ': keyCode: ' + keyCode + '<br>'
           );


    };

    $body.click(reportDomPath);
    $(doc).keypress(reportDomPath);   // only FF
```

But $(doc).keypress(reportDomPath) only works on FF.

Answer (score 0):

You are best to avoid adding these events with Javascript, I could not get any event to fire using javascript with FF5 for the life of me. What I found was that your Editor.html page should look something like this

```
<html>
<head><title>My editor</title></head>
<body contenteditable="true" onkeydown="return KeyDown_event(event)">
Edit me...
</body>
</html>
```

This has the most browser support and is the simplest way of doing it too.